# How to ls over files with arbitrary integer/number at position X in bash?

Tags: bash, ls

I'm trying to filter through a vast amount of .jar files in a folder in a bash script.
I wonder if I somehow can get files with an arbitrary integer at a position like for instance:

```
 ls ${name}-%i*
```

I'm trying to use it as below.
See line 6 in code below : fcount=...

```
for file in $(ls *.jar | sort -u)
do
    version=${file##*-}
    version=${version%".jar"}
    
    name=${file%-*}

    fcount=$(ls ${name}-* | wc -l )

    echo $name
    echo $file
    echo $version    
    echo $fcount

done
```

Comment: [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Sooo `ls ${name}-$i*`?

Comment: Ofc :P but does that force the $i value to be an integer? 

The problem is that files can be named:
name-1.0.jar
name-something-2.0.jar 

I want to count occurences of packages with same name but different versions. Using ls ${name}-$i* returns fcount 2 for first file, want it to be 1.

Comment: What about `${name}-[0-9]*.jar` ? Note that this selects the filenames with a digit following immediately the `-`. There may be non-digit characters after the first digit.

Comment: Yes, perfect :)

Comment: You should nearly never use `ls` in a shell script. It should be used mostly in interactive shells.